# How to write a generic dialog window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-7.0

I have a base class which is custom control without default template `SlimWindow`. It has little function - it removes Window header and some other stuff.

I have multiple windows inheriting from it which has similar behaviour - eg dialog windows. they have a header and ok/cancel buttons.

Since I cant inherit a proper window (with xaml and cs) - whats the best way to achieve the same functionality where the "subclassed" window will have XAML **and** code-behind?

It should:

- be able to provide `Title` and `Content` (part of the window between title and the Ok/Cancel button) for the "base" window.
- expose inner elements for styling (eg if I want to change OK button background colour) without writing dep props for every single property that comes to mind
- be able to run custom logic on Ok/Cancel/Close etc.
- integrate into the "base" window in few lines of XAML as automatically as possible.

*Additional consideration: I use devexpress themes, so I am not sure if a customcontrol default style in Themes/generic.xaml (as per the textbook) will work and/or be found by the current theme (they are user-selectable in run-time)*

Example of what I think the usage should look like:

```
<Window x:Class="DialogWindow.ADialogWindow" ...>
    <Grid>
        <local:DialogWindowControl TitleContent="A Title" OnOkClosed="onDialogOkClose">
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
            </Grid>
        </local:DialogWindowControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I dunno about the devexpress theming but you can give a template to a contentcontrol and then template out variable content within that. And a window itself is a contentcontrol. so maybe you only need one window, a template for your ok/cancel/close using datatriggers to control which buttons appear. Also rather depends on your requirements.

Comment: yes that what i have done.. thought may be there is another way (I havent tested the themes either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Since I cant inherit a proper window (with xaml and cs)"* - It looks like your problem is based on this wrong assumption. You can inherit from a `Window`, just don't define the base class using XAML. Instead define a default `Style`.
Preferably you would create a custom control that extends `Window` and add the default `Style` to the *Generic.xaml* `ResourceDictionary`.
In this `Style` you would override the `ControlTemplate` to implement the new dialog chrome (shared layout).
Dialogs that extend the new base class will add their content to the `Window.Content` property as usual.

**Dialog.cs**
The base class for all dialogs. It will contain a "Ok" and "Cancel" button at the bottom.

```cs
public class Dialog : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand DialogOkCommand { get; }

  static Dialog()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Dialog), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Dialog)));
    Dialog.DialogOkCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Closes the dialog and sets the DialogResult to 'true'", nameof(DialogOkCommand), typeof(Dialog));
  }

  public Dialog()
  {
    var dialogOkCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      Dialog.DialogOkCommand,
      ExecuteDialogOkCommand,
      CanExecuteDialogOkCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(dialogOkCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteDialogOkCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = CanCloseDialog(e.Parameter);

  private void ExecuteDialogOkCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => CloseDialog(e.Parameter);

  // Allow derived types to override/extend the behavior
  protected virtual bool CanCloseDialog(object commandParameter)
    => true;

  // Allow derived types to override/extend the behavior
  protected virtual void CloseDialog(object commandParameter)
  {
    this.DialogResult = true;  
    Close();
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**
Add the default `Style` that overrides the template.
Dialogs that extend `Dialog` will add their content to the `Window.Content` property as usual.
The "Ok" button will use the routed `Dialog.DialogOkCommand` assigned to `Button.Command`. The routed command is defined and handled in the `Dialog` base class.

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:Dialog">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition x:Name="DialogHeaderChromeRow"
                             Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRow" />
              <RowDefinition x:Name="DialogFooterChromeRow"
                             Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
              <ContentPresenter />
            </AdornerDecorator>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Button Content="Ok"
                      Command="{x:Static local:Dialog.DialogOkCommand}" />

              <!-- Because Button.IsCancel is 'true', clicking the Button 
                   will automatically close the dialog and set Window.DialogResult to 'false' -->
              <Button Content="Cancel"
                      IsCancel="True"
                      IsDefault="True" />
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Usage example

The following example dialog will display a `DatePicker` and the chrome it inherits from the `ControlTemplate` defined by the `Dialog` base class.
In this case, the dialog will inherit the "Ok" and "Cancel" `Button` located at the bottom (below its own `DatePicker` content) including the functionality (because it is implemented in the base class `Dialog`).

**DatePickerDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class DatePickerDialog : Dialog
{
  public DatePickerDialog()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  // TODO::Optionally override CanCloseDialog and CloseDialog
  // in case we want to extend the behavior of the Dialog base class.

  protected override bool CanCloseDialog(object commandParameter)
    => this.IsSelectedDateValid;
}
```

**DatePickerDialog.xaml**
When using the base class `Dialog` as root XAML element of the dialog,
the extended dialog `DatePickerDialog` will inherit the template of the `Dialog`. This means in this case it will contain a "Ok" and "Cancel" button.

```
<local:Dialog x:Class="DatePickerDialog"
              Title="DatePickerDialog"
              Height="450"
              Width="800">
  <DatePicker />
</local:Dialog>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
Example that shows how to handle the dialog.

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;
  }

  private void OnShowDialogClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog() 
    { 
      DataContext = this.MainViewModel.DatePickerDialogViewModel 
    };

    bool dialogResult = datePickerDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult)
    {
      // Do something when the "Ok" button was clicked
      this.MainViewModel.CommitDatePickerViewModelChanges();
    }
    else
    {
      // Do something when the "Cancel" button was clicked
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: good one. i have done exactly that. just wanted to see if there is another way. *note - title is a content inside the window as it has no Windows header* but close enough

Comment: It's a little bit different from your posted example in that the base class for all dialogs is already a `Window`. You then use this new base class as root element (to replace the `Window` element.

Comment: And don't forget to add the `AdornerDecorator`  otherwise you would miss it when you want to show adorners.

Comment: this is why i marked your answer ;)

Comment: "add the ÀdornerDecorator`" - I dont know how. I dont use them but devexpress data grid does for sure.. I am listening :) [to be precise - I use them in different app for fast text drawing, but not in a custom control - are those the same adorners with what you are talking about?]

Comment: I already added it in my example Style ;) I was just mentioning it because it was missing from your example. Just in case you continue to refactor your existing code. In case you want to add this dialog base class to your library, the `AdornerDecorator` is an important detail to save you from future head aches.

Comment: The `AdornerDecorator` just wraps the `ContentPresenter` for the `Window.Content`. That's all.

Comment: I have 2 of them. shall i wrap each individually or the whole parent Grid?

Comment: Yes, you should both of them otherwise the `ContentPresenter` for the title bar won't support adorners.

Comment: Sorry. No not individually. Better use the next common container. Or the top level Grid.

Comment: And the TitleContent property should be a normal dependency property defined on `Dialog`. Also the "Ok"  butoon should set the `Window.Result` property of the base `Window`. This way `ShowDialog` will return the proper value. If your "Cancel"  button has `Button.IsCancel` set to true you don't have to implement extra logic to close the dialog and set the `Result`.

Comment: `this.DialogResult = true;` (inside `Dialog` base class' "Ok" click handler).

Comment: Also your *"TODO find parent window and close it"* is now obsolete as you can directly call `Close()` on the current instance.

Comment: "directly call Close() on the current instance" this I dont uderstand. `ContentControl` does not have Close on it

Comment: But your base class is not `ContentControl`. It's `Window` (although `Window` is also a `ContentControl`. When you take a second look at ma example, you will notice t hat the base class for all dialogs `Dialog` is a `Window`. Now every class that extends `Dialog` like the `DatePickerDialog` in my example is able to close itself, because it inherits the `Window.Close()` member. Because it is a `Window`, your dialogs also inherit the `Window.ShowDialog` and `Window.DialogResult` members: `if (new DatePickerDialog().ShowDialog()) { // TODO::Handle dialog model to get the interaction results }`.

Comment: Do you want me to extend the example to show how the dialogs handle the CloseCommand? I would implement a CloseDialogCommand of type RoutedCommand. Then I would assign this command to the close Button in the `Dialog` base class template. Then the base class `Dialog` would implement the handling of this command and closes itself. I would implement the OnDialogClosing method that would be called by the command handler as `virtual` to allow extending dialogs to modify the behavior.

Comment: I have modified the example (including the usage example) to show how to implement the close feature in the base class whle allowing subclasses to modify the behavior (see usage example). It also shows how to set the `Window.DialogResult`.

Comment: here is another enigma for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316457/how-to-inherit-one-wpf-custom-control-from-another - this one I havent figure out yet

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done so far (Devexpress themes work just fine):

Custom control:

```
    public class DialogCustomControl : ContentControl
    {
        public DialogCustomControl()
        {
        }

        public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> OkButtonClick;

        Button okButton;
        Window parentWindow;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            okButton = GetTemplateChild("okButton") as Button;
            if (okButton != null)
            {
                okButton.Click += okButton_Click;
            }
        
            parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        }

        private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(OkButtonClick != null) OkButtonClick(this, e);
            parentWindow.Close();
        }

        public static object GetTitleContent(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(TitleContentProperty);
        }
        public static void SetTitleContent(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TitleContentProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TitleContent", typeof(object), typeof(DialogCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

Template in `app.xaml`:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DialogCustomControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DialogCustomControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding TitleContent}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
                                <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="80"/>
                                <Button Content="OK" x:Name="okButton" Width="80"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
```

Usage (can set title as a string or as a XAML content):

```
<Window x:Class="DialogWindow.ADialogWindow" ... >
    <Grid>
        <!-- TitleContent="A Title" -->
        <local:DialogCustomControl OkButtonClick="okButton_Click">
            <local:DialogCustomControl.TitleContent>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="A TITLE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </local:DialogCustomControl.TitleContent>
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
            </Grid>
        </local:DialogCustomControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```